# Entity Framework Core Foreign Key Not Working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

```
   base.OnModelCreating(builder);
  builder.Entity<MottoMobilIdentityUser>()
    .HasIndex(b => b.SeoUrl)
    .IsUnique();
  builder.Entity<Company>()
    .HasOne(p => p.City)
    .WithMany(b => b.Companies)
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.CityId);
```

And my view page is  `@Model.Company.City.Name`

but i have a  **null** error

And My Controller class fill model model not null because another data is work

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int id)
{

  var data = await _companyApiController.GetCompanyById(id);
  var model = new AdminDetailsViewModel
  {

    Company = data,

  };
  return View(model);
}
```

And My Model

```
 public int CityId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("CityId")]
public virtual City City { get; set; }
```

Comment: It's unclear what are you asking - you are including irrelevant information (`MottoMobilIdentityUser`) and not including relevant (the type of `Model`, how it get retrieved etc.) From what you wrote, most likely you forgot to eager load the `Model`.

Comment: Explain more, what relation you are going to create? what entities? include your classes

Answer (score 2):

You have null value cause its lazy evaluation.
Just use Include()`context.Companies.Where(r=>r.Id == Id).Include(r=>r.City).First()`